# Bootstrap button dropdown in tab pane causing overflow

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I'm using Bootstrap and have a form embedded in tab panes that contains button dropdowns. Sometimes the amount of items in the dropdowns overflows the height of the tab pane. I can always increase the min-height of the tab pane, but this solution is hackish. I have an example jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sudp7/1/

In it, you can see how the dropdown gets clipped at the bottom of the tab pane. Is there a way to make the dropdown menu overflow the height of its parent container? I have tried playing with the z-index and overflow-y properties to no avail. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If changing `overflow` is an option for you, then the right selector is `.tab-content`

```
.tab-content {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was sure z-index was the solution and I even set overflow-y to visible on the individual panes but not on the tab-content selector. Thanks again! Accepted and I'd upvote if I had the reputation to do so.